# One-liner to move files that match a pattern to a new directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, move

I need to move files in my home directory into a new directory. I need to select files with names that begin with a random set of 20 capital letters. The random set will consist of only 4 letters: T, A, G, or C. Because of the variability of names searched for, and the presence of names that would consist of 20 consecutive capital letters but without meeting the T, A, G, or C only requirement, a regex seems like the best option here.

I have tried to use a regular expression, but it doesn't work with this one-liner.

```
find source -name "([TAGC]{20})" -exec mv -i {} -t ~/dst \;
```

Is there a way of making this, or a similar, one-liner work for this situation, or do I need to write a script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What happens, what error do you get?

Comment: Try `-regex` instead of `-name`. You'll need one that matches the full name, not just a part of it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `-regex` option:

```
find . -regex ".*/[TAGC]{20}[^/]*$" -exec mv -i {} -t ~/dst \;
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex must match the entire filename which begin with ./

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./[TAGC]{20}' -print
```